# Jquery PNotify = bottomleft configuration doesn't work right

Tags: jquery, pnotify

Using the Pnotify Plugin 
http://sciactive.com/pnotify/

I'm trying to reposition it to the bottomleft corner of the screen, and have it push up the consecutive menus..

Positioning isn't a problem, but the direction of the notifiers are all stacking on top of each other (I only see the latest notification, the rest are behind it)

the code is supposed to be straight forward,

```
 var stack_bottomleft = {"dir1": "up", "dir2": "up", "push": "top"};

            new PNotify({
                title: "Title",
                type: "Success",
                text: "My Message 1",
                animation: "fade",
                animate_speed: 'fast',

                addclass: "stack-bottomleft",
                stack:    stack_bottomleft

            });

            new PNotify({
                title: "Title",
                type: "Success",
                text: "My Message 2",
                animation: "fade",
                animate_speed: 'fast',

                addclass: "stack-bottomleft",
                stack:    stack_bottomleft

            });


            new PNotify({
                title: "Title",
                type: "Success",
                text: "My Message 3",
                animation: "fade",
                animate_speed: 'fast',

                addclass: "stack-bottomleft",
                stack:    stack_bottomleft

            });
```

perhaps a bug?

Answer (score 1):

you have to take care where you create your stack. For example, don´t create it in an if-statement because it will **create a new stack for every notice** and the stacks will overlapp. I found this on the pnotify homepage in a comment on the index.html:

> ```
>   /*********** Custom Stacks ***********
>     * A stack is an object which PNotify uses to determine where
>     * to position notices. A stack has two mandatory variables, dir1
>     * and dir2. dir1 is the first direction in which the notices are
>     * stacked. When the notices run out of room in the window, they
>     * will move over in the direction specified by dir2. The directions
>     * can be "up", "down", "right", or "left". Stacks are independent
>     * of each other, so a stack doesn't know and doesn't care if it
>     * overlaps (and blocks) another stack. The default stack, which can
>     * be changed like any other default, goes down, then left. Stack
>     * objects are used and manipulated by PNotify, and therefore,
>     * should be a variable when passed. So, calling something like
>     *
>     * new PNotify({stack: {"dir1": "down", "dir2": "left"}});
>     *
>     * will **NOT** work. It will create a notice, but that notice will
>     * be in its own stack and may overlap other notices.
>     */
> ```

I had the same issue with:

```
            $rootScope.$watch('feedback',function(){
                if($rootScope.feedback){
                 var stack_bottomleft = {"dir1": "up", "dir2": "right", "firstpos1": 25, "firstpos2": 25};
                    new PNotify({
                        title: $rootScope.feedback.title,
                        text: $rootScope.feedback.text,
                        type: $rootScope.feedback.type,
                        addclass: 'stack-bottomleft',
                        stack: stack_bottomleft
                    });
                    $rootScope.feedback=null;
                }
            });
```

and fixed it with:

```
var stack_bottomleft = {"dir1": "up", "dir2": "right", "firstpos1": 25, "firstpos2": 25};
            $rootScope.$watch('feedback',function(){
                if($rootScope.feedback){
                    new PNotify({
                        title: $rootScope.feedback.title,
                        text: $rootScope.feedback.text,
                        type: $rootScope.feedback.type,
                        addclass: 'stack-bottomleft',
                        stack: stack_bottomleft
                    });
                    $rootScope.feedback=null;
                }
            });
```

I hope that will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Like it was [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25563784/1548719) by [**@Tristan Reifert**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3989209/tristan-reifert) there is a **crucial difference** between setting stack object inside notice init and transmitting that stack object to notice init params.

Thus, even next code will not work:

```
var showNotice = function () {
    var stack = {dir1: "up", dir2: "left", firstpos1: 25, firstpos2: 25},

    return new PNotify({
        title: 'Some title', text: 'Some text',
        addclass: "stack-bottomright",
        stack: stack
    });
}
```

The main point here is that the same-stack notices **should receive the one and the same stack object** configured for it. In the case shown above the new object will be initialized on each function call and each notice will receive different object.

To avoid it, all notices should address the same object. For e.g.:

```
    var stack = {dir1: "up", dir2: "left", firstpos1: 25, firstpos2: 25},
        showNotice = function () {     
            return new PNotify({
                title: 'Some title', text: 'Some text',
                addclass: "stack-bottomright",
                stack: stack
            });
        }
```

Doing so, each subsequent call of `showNotice()` will address the same stack object that previous notice addressed before.

Answer (score 0):

On PNotify 5.2.0

For me this only worked if the state was an instance of PNotify.Stack

```
defaultConfig.stack = new PNotify.Stack({
   dir1: "up", 
   dir2: "left",
   firstpos1: 25,
   firstpos2: 25, 
   push: "top",
   modal: false
});
```